# MongoDB 3.1/3.2 Java driver and GridFS

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

I just downloaded MongoDB v3.1.7 and [updated my pom](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) with the v3.1-SNAPSHOT driver, but I still don't see changes for GridFS to support the [new classes/API](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/index.html?com/mongodb/MongoClient.html).  It was [remarked on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mongodb-user/3.1$20gridfs/mongodb-user/zZE0Q7Z2AiM/x7a-CDTRsHUJ) (Mar 28, 2015) that the new GridFS changes where not included in 3.0, but would be part of 3.1.  Have they been included yet? Nothing was mentioned in the [latest blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/127802855483/mongodb-317-is-released) .

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sontatype Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Recent blog posts**:

- [MongoDB 3.1.7 is released (Aug 28, 2015)](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/127802855483/mongodb-317-is-released)
- [MongoDB 3.1.6 is released (Jul 21, 2015)](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/124686547743/mongodb-316-is-released)
- [MongoDB 3.1.5 is released (Jun 30, 2015)](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/122864829733/mongodb-315-is-released)

**UPDATE**:
I found the Jira "[Create new GridFS API](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1713?jql=component%3DGridFS%20and%20fixVersion%3D%273.1%27)" to migrate the GridFS API, which is marked RESOLVED for 3.1, but the changes are not in maven yet (and possibly the binary distribution). Anyone know how long it takes to make it's way to both the binary (if that's required) and the [maven repo](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT/)?

> **Create new GridFS API**
>
> Details
>
> ```
> Type: New Feature
> Status: Resolved
> Priority: Major - P3
> Resolution: Fixed
> Affects Version/s: None
> Fix Version/s: 3.1
> Component/s: GridFS
> Labels: None
> ```
>
> Description:
>
> ```
> Based on an upcoming cross-driver specification, this should use the
> idioms and classes introduced in the new CRUD APi, rather than the
> deprecated com.mongodb.DB API.
> ```
>
> Created: Mar 20 2015 09:55:04 PM GMT+0000
>   Updated: Sep 01 2015 04:25:41 PM GMT+0000
>   Resolved: **Sep 01 2015** 04:25:41 PM GMT+0000